# Trying to remove an element from a list in a database model class, but that list isn't being updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

## My Table and Class Setup

I have a database which I am trying to design an ASP.NET Web API for, however I am facing issues when attempting to update an element in a list.

The tables I am using are structured as follows. An activity in this instance is a genre of outdoor activity, it could be running, sailing, kayaking and the like. In this system I would like users to be able to select activities they would like to 'subscribe to'. To achieve this, I have a link table that will link a user to an activity.

User
| Id | UserName | Email |
| -------- | -------------- | --- |

Activity
| Id | ActivityName |
| --| -----------|

User_Activity
| UserId | ActivityId |
| -------- | -------------- |

I have scaffolded the database to create the different models to represent this, and that came back with the following classes

```cs
public partial class Activity
{
    public Activity()
    {
        Members = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string ActivityName { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public virtual ICollection<User> Members { get; set; }
}
```

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{    
    public User()
    {
        Activities = new HashSet<Activity>();
        
    }    

    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }    
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;   
    
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    
}
```

In my database context file it also correctly displays the foreign and primary key relationships from my database.

I found an article in Microsoft's documentation that covers the concept of a Data Transfer Object, so I have created DTO classes for these two database models.

```
public partial class ActivityDTO
{
    public ActivityDTO()
    {
        
    }
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string ActivityName { get; set; } = null!;
    
}
```

```
public class UserDTO
{    
    public UserDTO()
    {
        Activities = new HashSet<ActivityDTO>();       
    }    

    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }    
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;   
     
    
    public virtual ICollection<ActivityDTO> Activities { get; set; }   
}
```

Since the Activity class had a reference to members, I discovered that performing requests with that created a so called reference cycle, so I made this DTO class in an attempt to avoid that.

## The Problem

In my UsersController, I have a put request with two inputs, the user ID and an activityID, with the aim of adding that activity on the list of activities belonging to that user. This code works correctly, I can see that the activity ID is correctly added to the list of activities when get that user.

```
[HttpPut("{UserId}/Activity/{ActivityId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutActivityOnUser(int UserId, int ActivityId)
{
    var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(UserId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        var activity = await _context.Activities.FindAsync(ActivityId);
        if (activity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!user.Activities.Contains(activity))
            {
                user.Activities.Add(activity);
                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return Ok();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateException)
                {
                    return StatusCode(500, "User's Activity could not be updated");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "User already has that activity");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This code works correctly, I can see that the activity ID is correctly added to the list when I call my getUsers method shown below.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDTO>> GetUser(int id)
{
    if (_context.Users == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var user = await _context.Users
        .Include(u => u.Activities)     
        .Select(u => new UserDTO
        {
            MemberId = u.MemberId,
            UserName = u.UserName,
            Email = u.Email,            
                    
            Activities = u.Activities.Select(a => new ActivityDTO
            {
                ActivityId = a.ActivityId,
                ActivityName = a.ActivityName,

            }).ToList(),
        })
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.MemberId == id);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    
    return user;

}
```

However, the remove method is not yielding the correct results.

```cs
[HttpDelete("{UserId}/Activity/{ActivityId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteActivityFromUser(int UserId, int ActivityId)
{

    var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(UserId);          

    if (user == null)           {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var activity = await _context.Activities.FindAsync(ActivityId); 


    user.Activities.Remove(activity);
    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "User's Activity could not be removed");
    }
}
```

If I input UserID 2, and Activity 11, both of which exist in the database, I will get a 200 response OK message back, but when I get that user's details again I see that nothing has changed.

Stepping through the code, on the line `user.Activities.Remove(activity)` I can see that user.Activities has count 0, there is nothing in the list of activities belonging to that user. I feel like I need to use a similar technique as the getUser method to retrieve the list of activities as a DTO object, to avoid the reference cycle, but when I tried that I found I couldn't remove the element from the list since the object types were not the same as the ones stored on the database.

So if I have this Users model, which holds a list of Activities, but each Activity also holds a reference to a list of Users, how can I update element of that list without introducing reference cycling?

Comment: The controller is on the server.  The view is on the browser on the client.  The client view needs to be updated.  See following two links :  1) Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522401/i-need-to-update-the-model-view-and-reflect-those-changes-in-database 2) Learn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing some extra digging, and I believe I have found the solution.

In accordance with this article here, It appears that I was simply getting an instance of the activity from the activity table and trying to remove it, I was under the assumption that the item being requested in the Remove method was simply meant to be an object that matches the one you want to remove. But following this article I found that I could actually just get the actual activity from the User object and remove that link straight from there.

A simpler solution than I thought, but it appears to work as I originally intended.

https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/updating-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-5-and-above/

```cs
[HttpDelete("{UserId}/Activity/{ActivityId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteActivityFromUser(int UserId, int ActivityId)
{

    var user = await _context.Users.Include(u => u.Activities).SingleAsync(u => u.MemberId == UserId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }


    var activity = user.Activities.Single(a => a.ActivityId == ActivityId);

    user.Activities.Remove(activity);


    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "User's Activity could not be removed");
    }
}
```